# call Nodejs function from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I want to execute a function inside a remote URL. I know the page URL where the function is and I know the Function name too. The server-side application is built on NodeJs Express. And the function itself look like this

```
    function executer(param1, parama2){
    //logic
    return true;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You must know an endpoint(url) that leads to a function and then just call it using AJAX for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example an AJAX call to trigger an endpoint on server like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/remoteservice/executer/",
  type: "get",
  data: {"param1": "param1","param2":"param2"}, 
  success: function(result){
    alert("Job is done");
  }
});
```

But you need to know the endpoint(url) and the method that it waits(get, post or whatever)

Comment: Which one is the function name here??

Comment: Function name here is url, it's a remote API address.

Answer (score 1):

If it is some API. Then you can use any node module for request like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). First is for callback and second for promises based. Examples are listed in modules description.